# WSO2 ESB Proxy using Python or Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2 ESB and am attempting to get a very simple proxy (I think) set up. For this testing environment I have two python scripts, a server and a client, that I just want to get talking to each other. I could also use Ruby instead if that would be easier.

I have gone through the [getting started guide](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/quickstart_guide.html#Proxy) and created a new proxy, however then it is telling me I need to use axis2 which looks like it is only for Java. Am I missing something completely, or is there something else that I can use? If possible I would like the ESB to connect directly with the server script and the client script.

If you have any experience in this area and could just point me in the right direction I would be very appreciative.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate your server and client, you should know from what protocol that the client-server communication happens. (For eg: HTTP)
WSO2 ESB is capable of handling various standard transports such as HTTP, JMS, VFS etc. and protocols such as SOAP, REST etc. 
So, in what protocol that you wish to communicate between client and server.

Comment: I was trying to communicate using REST. I ended up using UltraESB which worked much better. Thanks.